# How to insert dynamic data in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I just want to insert dynamic generated input field data into database . My db table having three fields , **id(Auto Increment), product_name and rate** . I'm trying to insert bulk data into database using dynamically generated input fields where I can add/remove input fields manually.
[image]
 I created the input fields as

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Product Name" name="prodname[]" type="text">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Product Rate" name="prodrate[]" type="text">
```

This is my controller below

```
function Act_AddProducts() {
        if ( $this->input->post( 'prodname' )&&$this->input->post( 'prodrate' )) {
            foreach ( $this->input->post( 'prodname' ) as $key => $value ) {

                $this->ProductModel->add_products( $value );
            }

        }
```

Model function is below

```
function add_products($val)
  {
      if($this->db->insert('tbl_product_master', array('product_name' => $val)))
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
  }
```

Now the value is inserting into db but one at a time. So please help me to identify the issue with code. Also I don't really understand how to insert **prodrate[]** value into the same insert query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hope this will help you**

*Your controller `Act_AddProducts` should be like this :*

```
function Act_AddProducts() 
{
   $prodnames = $this->input->post( 'prodname' );
   $prodrates = $this->input->post( 'rate' );
    if ( ! empty($prodnames) && ! empty($prodrates) ) 
    {
        foreach ($prodnames as $key => $value ) 
        {
            $data['product_name'] = $value;
            /* make sure product_rate columns is correct i just guess it*/
            $data['product_rate'] = $prodrates[$key];
            $this->ProductModel->add_products($data);
        }

    } 
}
```

*Your model `add_products` should be like this :*

```
function add_products($data)
{
   if ( ! empty($data))
   {
      $this->db->insert('tbl_product_master', $data);
   }
}
```

Comment: make sure  name of `product_rate` column is `product_rate` otherwise change it into controller as u not give rate column name

Comment: Do you mean **function add_products($data)** in model?

Comment: I tried your code, but only the first value is inserting into the db.

Comment: what is the column name for product rate ? did u get any error?

Comment: Column names are okay and I'm not getting any error.

Comment: sorry forget to change `$val`  in  `add_products($val)` to this `add_products($data)` so updated my answer now pls check

Comment: ok do `print_r($data);die;` in `Act_AddProducts` method before insert query and let me show what u get?

Comment: I'm getting this result-> **Array ( [product_name] => product 1 [product_rate] => 110 )** .No looping is happening

Comment: ok your data is ok. i have just changed model method `add_products` , copy it and try with it, and let me know what u get?  see my updated answer

Comment: I tried to insert 3 row values(productname & rate). But only first row textbox value is inserting.

Comment: Do you think am I missing something in View ?

Comment: let me see your full form

Comment: First error : `$this->input->post( 'product_rate' );`   should be `$this->input->post( 'rate' );` not `product_rate` since your input name is `rate`, Second your dynamic generated input type missing `name attributes` in js code, pls fix this ,

Comment: @Pradeep Sir its nice & good for us if you will explain it also with comment.

Answer (score 0):

just pass input value to the model as it is, then use foreach inside model

```
function add_products($val)
{
   foreach ( $val as $key => $value ) {

            $this->db->insert('tbl_product_master', array('product_name' => $value );
        }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try. Also can you show how to insert the **Rate** ?

Comment: No, Its not working. Only first input value is inserting.

Comment: don't use return insert foreach in model... even after removing model, only one data is inserting... I can provide a sample code... But in this code instead of model I made everything in controller... just go through that

Answer (score 0):

> TRY THIS
>
> controller

```
function Act_AddProducts() {
$product_rate = $data = array();

$product_rate = $this->input->post( 'prodrate' );
$product_name = $this->input->post( 'prodname' )
        if ( !empty($this->input->post( 'prodname' ))&&!empty($this->input->post( 'prodrate' ))) {
            foreach ( $product_name as $key => $value ) {
            $data['product_name'] = $value;
            $data['product_rate'] = $product_rate[$key];
                $this->ProductModel->add_products($data);
            }

        }
```

> model

```
      function add_products($data)
  {
        $product_name = $data['product_name'];
        $product_rate = $data['product_rate'];
      if($this->db->insert('tbl_product_master', array('product_name' => $product_name,'product_rate' => $product_rate)))
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just for your reference.... A simple sample code for dynamic insert.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Checking extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{ 
echo "<form method='post' action='". base_url("Checking/save") ."'>";
    for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
            echo "<input type='text' name='input_text[]'>";
    }
    echo "<button type='submit'>Submit</button></form>";
}

public function save(){
    foreach($this->input->post("input_text") as $Row){
        $this->db->insert("checking",array("input_text"=>$Row['input_text']));
    }
}
}
```

create a controller as Checking.php, and run this .. you will get idea

For database

```
CREATE TABLE `checking` (
`ch` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`input_text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ch`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: For immediate purpose I did everything in controller, Just take this as a sample to get some idea as you are a fresher. Do the insert section inside the model

Answer (score 0):

If you want upload bulk record then use insert_batch instead of simple insert
 your Controller should be

```
function Act_AddProducts() 
{
$product_rate = $_POST['prodrate'];
$product_name = $_POST['prodname'];

if(!empty($product_rate) && !empty($product_rate)){
$data_array = array();
  foreach ($product_rate as $key => $value ) 
        { 
            $tmp_array = array();
            $tmp_array['product_name'] = $value;
            $tmp_array['product_rate'] = $product_rate[$key];
      $data_array[] = $tmp_array;
        }
   $this->ProductModel->add_products($data_array);
}
```

model should be

```
function add_products($data)
  {


      if($this->db->insert_batch('tbl_product_master', $data))
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Where are you calling model in the controller in your answer?

Comment: Sorry by mistake i forgot to call model just edited code.

Comment: No, its not the problem with the variable name. Its not lopping inside foreach or not getting as array from the form. Do you think am I missing something in View ?

Comment: please put this top of the function and share screen short after submit  echo  '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); exit;